# Reversing d3 bar chart loading animation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have been working on creating a bar chart in JavaScript with the d3 library. I wanted to include a loading animation with this code:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(sortedPartyArray) 
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
        .style("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr('x', (s) => xScale(s[0]) + 40)
        .attr('y', (s) => yScale(s[1]) + 19.5)
        .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
          .attr('height', 0)  //on load animation
          .transition()
          .delay((d, i) => {return i*50})
          .duration(800)
          .attr('height', (s) => height - yScale(s[1]));
```

Essentially this does what its supposed to do; it creates an animation for when the chart is loaded . The only issue I have is that the animation loads the bars from top to bottom, but I want the bars to load from bottom to top. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply transition to both **y** and **height**

Please check carefully initial `y` - I suppose it should be `height + 19.5`...

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(sortedPartyArray) 
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
        .style("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr('x', (s) => xScale(s[0]) + 40)
        .attr('y', height + 19.5)
        .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
        .attr('height', 0)
        .transition()
        .delay((d, i) => {return i*50})
        .duration(800)
        .attr('y', (s) => yScale(s[1]) + 19.5)
        .attr('height', (s) => height - yScale(s[1]));
```